# DOM mutation warning in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on an app that is displaying the following warning. I'm wanting to understand what it is and eliminate if possible.

[Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.

Comment: Could you include the code that gives rise to this warning in the question?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Check the source of the warning by hovering your mouse over the top right underlined line. It will have the format of file-name.js:line-number. In my case the cause was not the React app but a Chrome extension, Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer (by Google) to be exact. Once I disabled the extension, the warning went away. Hope this helps.